# How to add climate clock widget in my angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How can I add this https://climateclock.world/widget in my angular project?

after adding

```
<script src="https://climateclock.world/widget-v2.js" async></script>
<script src="https://climateclock.world/flatten.js" async></script>
<climate-clock />
```

in the HTML file, I get the following error

```
ERROR in Errors parsing template: Only void and foreign elements can be self closed "climate-clock" 
("d/widget-v2.js" async></script>
<script src="https://climateclock.world/flatten.js" async></script>
[ERROR ->]<climate-clock />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a few things:

Change `<climate-clock />` to `<climate-clock></climate-clock>`

Allow foreign elements in your module, add schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA] to your app module - this tells angular to allow elements it is not familiar with in your templates:

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
```

Make sure you load the external scripts in your main index.html

see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zcu4cb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) for a working sample